# Is mounting HFS+ r/w safe?

Tags: hfs+

is mounting journaled HFS+ partitions as r/w with hfsprogs and "-o force" prams safe? I mean, will power failure broke filesystem and etc.? Or is it as safe as ntfs on Linux?

Comment: I've heard it's not recommended. Nevertheless, I've mounted my Mac filesystem on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS multiple times to share files between OSes (`ext4` can't be mounted on Mac without 3rd party software) with no issues. However, I would also like to know what the consequences can be.